# How to get the url and title of the current page in safari?

Tags: javascript, url, safari, safari-extension

I am developing a safari extension and for my extension to work, I need to get the url and title of the tab i am currently in. I know how to get it for chrome and firefox but I am feeling it difficult to find for safari. So can some help me out with this. And i am building the extension using css, html and javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could take the url in any browser as simple as:

```
document.URL
```

While you can get the title as simple as:

```
document.title
```

Comment: `document.location.href` for URL

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to get the URL and title from the global page, you can use `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url` and `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.title`.

See: [Safari Extensions Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingButtonstotheMainSafariToolbar/AddingButtonstotheMainSafariToolbar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH3-SW1)